# body background overlapping bootstrap column on mobile when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I reduced my css and body code as much as possible and yet still when I scroll on mobile device at a normal speed the body background `white` color overlaps content for a brief second.

**css**

```
body {
}
```

**html**

```
<div style="overflow-x:hidden; margin-top: 46px;">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

It is only a second before the content is yielded, but nevertheless it is frustrating to see when you do a lot of scrolling.

And this happens continues to happen even after the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Site is www.livetochallenge.com if you want to see for yourself. It works fine on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of your phone or browser. Try on a different device. There is no obvious reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Yea but it doesn't happen on other websites I go to with my iPhone using google chrome.

Comment: Try setting z-index: 0; on the body.

Comment: Please provide more code and jsfidle. I can not help you wihtout these.